# In VBA, are template global variables accessible by documents and sub-templates?

Tags: vba, office-2010

I am writing a template in Word 2010 which is based upon another template, both of which contain considerable amounts of VBA code. I have referenced the original template to access its modules. Are global variables in the original template also accessible this way? If so, is there a coding standard to access them, such as:

```
TheTemplate.VariableName
```

or can they just be accessed by name:

```
VariableName
```

Comment: If they are truly visible, I'd fully qualify any reference regardless. You never know what functions/properties will be written in the future that would cause ambiguity. It's always best to be as explicit as possible and not let the compiler make guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each template is a closed object. None of the variables global to it a template's modules will be accessible or visible to any other template that is currently loaded.

What you can do is add public properties to a document object. Add them to the "ThisDocument" class module every document has, for example a string property like this:

```vb
Public Property Get Foo() As String
  Foo = "Any value"
End Property
```

Now you can access that property from anywhere, as it will be exposed by that `Document` object:

```vb
MsgBox Application.Documents("appropriate document reference").Foo
' alerts "Any value"
```